# whether vs either

Tags: difference

What are the differences between "whether" and "either"?

For me, they mean about the same, something about the choice between 2 or more things.

- I want to eat ***either*** an apple or a banana.
- People became healthier ***whether*** because of intake of apples or bananas.

Are they absolutely the same?

Comment: So if you swapped *either* for *whether* in the first sentence, would it seem correct to you? Then, if you swapped *whether* for *either* in the second sentence, would that look right?

Comment: This tricky answer isn't an answer :)

Comment: Indeed it isn't. It might give you food for thought to help clear things up for you bit by bit, though.

Comment: does the second sentence sound awkward with any of the options, or is it just me?

Comment: I will eat either an apple or a banana whether i'm hungry or not. Whether it's a determiner or conjunction, be wary of either. :P

Answer (score 0):

"whether" and "either" are two different words pragmatically. There is a slight difference between them, and they are not quite the same.

For a start, both are fixed expressions, which means you should be careful not confuse them with one another.

> 1. whether ... or ... ( meaning: *it is not important if* );
>
> whether ... or not ( meaning: *if, or not* );
>
> 2. either ... or ... ( meaning:  *there is a choice between two possibilities* );

Now that I've covered the differences, you can decide which to use and when.

for example

1. He seemed undecided *whether* to go *or* stay. (a doubt between alternatives);
2. It's fine to do *either.*

Comment: Thank you! May you add some examples to your answer, please?

Comment: @LoveLanguagesAndPeople How about now?